# Understanding variable scope with regard to anonymous functions in EventListeners

Tags: javascript, parameters, scope, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

In the example below, it's the **green square** I'm interested in.

I get that clicking on the **red** square returns the value of the variable set higher up.

I get that clicking on the **blue** square returns the parameter's default value.

I get that clicking on the **orange** square simply returns the `event` object.

But *why* does clicking on the *green square* not pass in the value from the variable set higher up?

Why is the value returned as `undefined`?

Is it possible to pass the value from the variable set higher up into the anonymous function in the `EventListener` method? Or is this simply impossible?

**Example:**

```js
const square1 = 'red';
const square2 = 'orange';
const square3 = 'green';
const square4 = 'blue';

document.querySelector('.square.one').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(square1));

document.querySelector('.square.two').addEventListener('click', (square2) => console.log(square2));

document.querySelector('.square.three').addEventListener('click', (e, square3) => console.log(square3));

document.querySelector('.square.four').addEventListener('click', (e, square4 = 'blue') => console.log(square4));
```

```css
.square {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square.one {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.square.two {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

.square.three {
  background-color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
}

.square.four {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="square one">Click Me</div>
<div class="square two">Probably don't click me</div>
<div class="square three">Click Me</div>
<div class="square four">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Same reason why the orange square logs the event value: that's the value of the parameter with which the function was called.

Comment: @Bergi - Ah. Thanks. So (bear with me) how can I ensure that the parameter `green` in the anonymous function has the same value I've already given to `const green` at the top? I had thought, having set `const green`, that's the variable I was passing into the anonymous function.

Comment: Just don't declare a parameter at all! Then you won't get what the caller is passing (`undefined` in this case, since there's only one argument to event listeners) but instead it will refer to the upper-scope variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the value returned as `undefined`?

Your callback is accepting 2 parameters, `e` and `square3`. The `square3` parameter overrides the `square3` global variable in the callback scope. Since `addEventListener` only passes one parameter (the event) to the callback, the second parameter is `undefined`.

To fix this, just remove it from the parameter list. So, use `(e) => //...` instead of `(e, square3) => //...`

```js
const square1 = 'red';
const square2 = 'orange';
const square3 = 'green';
const square4 = 'blue';

document.querySelector('.square.one').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(square1));

document.querySelector('.square.two').addEventListener('click', (square2) => console.log(square2));

document.querySelector('.square.three').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(square3));

document.querySelector('.square.four').addEventListener('click', (e, square4 = 'blue') => console.log(square4));
```

```css
.square {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square.one {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.square.two {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

.square.three {
  background-color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
}

.square.four {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="square one">Click Me</div>
<div class="square two">Probably don't click me</div>
<div class="square three">Click Me</div>
<div class="square four">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Spectric. So, to clarify, _unless_ given a default value, _all_ parameters in an anonymous function in an `EventListener` (except the first one, which is always the `event object`) are `undefined`?

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine Yep, that's right. Any parameter of a function which is not given a value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You get 'undefined' because the call back function is expecting a 'square3' parameter which you are not passing.

Basically the square3 that you have defined above is not the same defined within the function scope

The call back function is only passing the event object

You can view the function parameter like variables definitions, which values are defined when we call the function

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass the value from the variable set higher up into the anonymous function in the EventListener method? Or is this simply impossible?

It's probably not needed very often, but for the sake of clarity, one might occasionally wish to **explicitly** include a parameter with a clearly stated value within an anonymous function within an `EventListener`.

In the course of asking the question and experimenting with various approaches, I've realised that this *is possible*, but you need to reference the already declared variable via a parameter default value.

**e.g.**

```
document.querySelector('.square.three').addEventListener('click', (e, mySquare3 = square3) => console.log(mySquare3));
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const square1 = 'red';
const square2 = 'orange';
const square3 = 'green';
const square4 = 'blue';

document.querySelector('.square.one').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(square1));

document.querySelector('.square.two').addEventListener('click', (square2) => console.log(square2));

document.querySelector('.square.three').addEventListener('click', (e, mySquare3 = square3) => console.log(mySquare3));

document.querySelector('.square.four').addEventListener('click', (e, square4 = 'blue') => console.log(square4));
```

```css
.square {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square.one {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.square.two {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.square.three {
  background-color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
}

.square.four {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="square one">Click Me</div>
<div class="square two">I've been disabled</div>
<div class="square three">Click Me</div>
<div class="square four">Click Me</div>
```